# Unity gun not smoothly following camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I am making a 3D game on unity and I want my pistol to move with the camera smoothly and not just attached to the camera. I'm not really sure how to explain it properly but what I mean is I want when I jump, for the gun to move up and down so it really looks like I'm holding it. Hope I don't sound really stupid right now :)

Any help appreciated!

Vector3 offset = PlayerMovement.Instance.FindVelRelativeToLook() * posOffset;
        float fallSpeed = PlayerMovement.Instance.GetFallSpeed() * posOffset;
        Vector3 desiredPos = defaultPos - new Vector3(offset.x, y: fallSpeed, z: offset.y);
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(current: transform.localPosition, target: desiredPos, currentVelocity: ref posVel, posSpeed);

I'm not gonna lie, I hardly understand half of this lol.

Comment: Not really sure if your weapon camera is a child of your main camera but either way just have a method which slightly moves the weapon when you jump and move it back when you land.

Comment: The weapon is a child of the camera, I forgot to mention it is an fps. I also want it to move left and right smoothly when u are moving in those directions, or if u are moving ur camera the gun rotates slightly, apologies if my explanation is bad.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/190206/avert-fate-cameragun-movement.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply... I believe that he is using another language rather than c#, and I am still new to programming so I am unable to translate

Comment: No, that's C#.  As far as Unity is concerned.  He didn't format his code at all.  It starts with `var speed` and ends with `update the actual weapon rotation }`

Comment: Oh, well it doesn't seem to work for me, not sure if I'm doing anything wrong but everything is red

Comment: Check this out.  Tons of scripts and many Camera scripts.  Some are written in Javascript and UnityScript but they can be translated very easily.   https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Scripts/Controllers

Comment: @jiveturkey I can't find one that solves my problem... I found this YouTuber known as Dani, he shows us a few lines of code that he used to achieve this effect (I added script to question) When I try to put this in my game I get many errors, for example when I write PlayerMovement.Instance, unity highlights it incorrect. Not sure if you are following but I tried :)